# Does jQuery ajax call always bring the sessionID cookie?

Tags: jquery, session, session-cookies

I am trying to secure my RESTful APIs. Currently, these RESTful APIs are invoked by from HTML page with jQuery ajax call. I noticed that for every ajax call, a cookie containing the sessionID is always sent along. That's why I am using a servlet filter to check for a session and see if proper authentication info is already in it. If not found, user is not authenticated and ajax call will fail.

But does jQuery ajax call always bring the sessionID cookie? Is this determined by jQuery or by the browser setting?

Comment: Probably you don't want to append the sessionID to your ajax request, It will pass by the browser as header information. What is the issue you faced?

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Currently I am relying the sessionID cookie header to authenticate the request to my RESTful API.  I want to know sending this header is a browser's behavior or jQuery's behavior. And I think session approach is not a good one for non-browser client.